# CSS hover command problems

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

I want the list item: Home, dashboard, and Contact Us to be green when hovered over. It turns green but it also moves in really random spots. These first two code bits are the parts of code that I am having trouble with, the last two are my full code just in case you need it. Thank you for your time.

```
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="cats">
        <li class="listItems" id="home">Home</li>
        <li class="listItems" id="dashboard">Dashboard</li>
        <li class="listItems" id="contactUs">Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#home:hover {
    padding:6px;
    width:100px;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#96F29C;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    left:70px;
}
#dashboard:hover {
    padding:6px;
    width:100px;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#96F29C;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    left:70px;
}
#contactUs:hover {
    padding:6px;
    width:100px;;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#96F29C;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    left:60px;
}
```

That is obviously not my full code but just in case you need it here my full code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ramabhadra' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="cats">
        <li class="listItems" id="home">Home</li>
        <li class="listItems" id="dashboard">Dashboard</li>
        <li class="listItems" id="contactUs">Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdownHome">
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Event Calender</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Bookings</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Picture Gallery</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Login</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Sign Up</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdownDashboard">
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Saved Info</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Friends</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Document</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Profile</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Account</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdownContactUs">
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Email</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Forum</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Phone-numbers</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Facebook</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Twitter</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color:black;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    z-index:1;
}
li {
    color:white;
    display:inline;
    width:100%
}
.cats {
    padding:6px;
    width:100%;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
}
#home:hover {
    padding:6px;
    width:100px;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#96F29C;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    left:70px;
}
#dashboard:hover {
    padding:6px;
    width:100px;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#96F29C;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    left:70px;
}
#contactUs:hover {
    padding:6px;
    width:100px;;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#96F29C;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    left:60px;
}
.listItems {
    padding:70px;
}
.dropdownHome {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:relative;
    left:18px;
    bottom:10px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:-1;
    border-radius:13px;
}
.dropdownDashboard {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:relative;
    right:290px;
    bottom:214px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:-1;
    float:right;
    border-radius:13px;
}
.dropdownContactUs {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:relative;
    left:140px;
    bottom:214px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:-1;
    float:right;
    border-radius:13px;
}
.catLists {
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    right:20;
    font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
}
.catListItem {
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hvwxnen0/1

Comment: Thank you so much. I just removed the padding in the code you posted and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

It is moving and flashing because you're changing the size and positioning **only** on hover.

Try this :

```
.cats li {
    padding:6px;
    width:100px;
    font-size:29px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    left:60px;
}

.cats li:hover {
    color:#96F29C;
}
```

Demo here : https://jsfiddle.net/mvzson9c/

Edit: Previous link was wrong, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It's not necesary to make so many definitions for de hoover option. If you only change the color just make it this way:

```
#home:hover {
    color:#96F29C;
}
```

The other definitions make the menu jump and flash.